# How to beat one or two egg yolks?

Tags: eggs, mixing

Many sauces and pastries call for beaten yolks. You need to beat yolks well, till they are thick again and are lemon-colored, so using mixer is a must. 
But if you need only one or two egg yolks, regular mixers are too big for the task. What I'm currently using is a battery-driven micro mixer, and it is not powerful enough and eats up batteries fast.
Can anybody suggest a good solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use currently - a drill on a high speed using the micro mixer attachement. I think [Dremel Stylus](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/Tools/Pages/ToolDetail.aspx?pid=1100) on low would work as well, but I don't have that one.

When I make waffles for 4 people, I use 4 yolks and my immersion blender gets the traction needed, but for two yolks I need a narrow glass and this.

[image: Drill Mixer]

Answer (score 18):

Using a mixer is not "a must". You should be able to whisk 1-2 egg yolks together quite easily which a whisk and some elbow grease. How do you think we beat egg yolks for the centuries prior to electricity?

Comment: With elaborate systems of levers and pulleys, obviously.  Don't you know *any* history? :P

Comment: @Aaronut : I always assumed they used some form of braided leather.  I mean, why else would it be called 'beating' and 'whipping' ?

Comment: There is a difference between yolks beaten for 30 seconds and 3 minutes with electric mixer. When done by hand, 3 minutes would be like 15?

Answer (score 8):

I don't even bother with a whisk for something that small.  (the only wisk I have is medium sized balloon whisk, I don't have any small ones).

I find a fork and a small bowl work well for up to about 3-4 eggs.  I tip the bowl towards hand with the fork so I can get a better angle on it, and it keeps the eggs from spreading out too much across the bowl.

Answer (score 6):

I think a great option for beating small amounts, if you don't just use a whisk, is a hand-cranked egg beater. They're cheap and easy to use. I have one I got from my Mom many years ago, and it works great. If you get one, don't let batter or egg or whatever dry on it--wash (or at least rinse) as soon as you're done using it. They're hard to get dried-on stuff off of because the spaces are small.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use my [immersion blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_blender), which gets plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried tilting your blender? i had the same problem for awhile and tilting the blender so the blades could reach the eggs did the trick. just be sure to have a firm, two hand hold; one on the base of the blender and one on the glass. then just tilt the top towards you.

Answer (score 0):

One option I've found works well is, I had picked up a immersion little milk frother gadget, and it works like a tiny immersion blender.

Honestly, I find beating eggs can be done just fine by hand, with a fork and a bowl or with a whisk (sometimes just "churning" between the hands if the whisk is too large or the quantity or bowl too small), but the little frother works when I've lumps to be worked out of something, or actual blending would be nice but the quantity is small - and since I've got it, I can use it for things like beating eggs if I'm in a hurry or feeling lazy.